# Check named return error using defer function

Tags: go

Hi I want to write a generic function to trace error message when a function returns error. So I wrote this:

```
func TraceError1(err *error) {
    if err != nil && *err != nil {
        pc := make([]uintptr, 15)
        n := runtime.Callers(2, pc)
        frames := runtime.CallersFrames(pc[:n])
        frame, _ := frames.Next()
        fmt.Printf("%s:%d %s\n", frame.File, frame.Line, frame.Function)
    }
}

func TraceError2(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        pc := make([]uintptr, 15)
        n := runtime.Callers(2, pc)
        frames := runtime.CallersFrames(pc[:n])
        frame, _ := frames.Next()
        fmt.Printf("%s:%d %s\n", frame.File, frame.Line, frame.Function)
    }
}

func foo() (err error) {
    defer TraceError1(&err)
    defer TraceError2(err)

    fmt.Println("do something")

    return fmt.Errorf("haha")
}
```

`TraceError1` works but `TraceError2` didn't. In my understanding, `error` is an interface so it is a pointer/address, why do I need to pass its address? Why `TraceError2` cannot work? Thanks.

Comment: If `foo` is the only funtion called from `main` there isn't any output, btw.

Comment: Use `defer func() { TraceError2(err) }()` to ensure `err` is evaluated at the end of the function not at the start.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `TraceError1` you are passing a pointer to the named return value `err`. The pointer is non-nil, but the value it points at (`err`) is nil (at the time of defer). However, it is not yet evaluated (dereferenced) because `TraceError1` has not yet been called. By the time the function does run (after `foo` returns) and the pointer gets dereferenced, the value of `err` has been updated (by the return statement inside `foo`).

However, in case of `TraceError2`, a nil interface **value** is passed, which will stay nil even when `TraceError2` executes eventually.

[Here is a simpler example](https://goplay.space/#GQZSSEsZcMh):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func intByValue(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("i = %d\n", i)
    //                     ^--- `i` is an integer value
    //                      --- whatever i was passed to the function, gets printed
}

func intByRef(i *int) {
    var v int = *i // i is a pointer to an int, which gets dereferenced here
    //                the *address* where the actual value resides was passed
    //                while the address stays the same, its value can change before
    //                i is dereferenced, and its value stored in v.
    fmt.Printf("i = %d\n", v)
}

func main() {
    var i int

    defer intByValue(i) // passed the *value* of i, which is 0 right now
    defer intByRef(&i)  // passed a *pointer* to i, which contains 0 right now

    i = 100 // before intByRef could "dereference" its argument, the value that it
    // contained has been updated

    // intByRef gets called, dereferences the value, finds 100, prints it.
    // intByValue gets called, finds 0, prints it
    // result should be:
    //     i = 100
    //     i = 0
}
```

So unfortunately, if you want the ability to update the error (e.g. by returning a named return value) before it gets used by the deferred function, you are going to have to pass around *pointers* to the variable.

In other words, `TraceError2` is simply not suited for your use case.

Edit: use correct terminology and (questionably) improve example code.

Answer (score 2):

As [go blog](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) explained

> The behavior of defer statements is straightforward and predictable.
> There are three simple rules:
>
> 1. A deferred function's arguments are evaluated when the defer statement is evaluated.
> 2. Deferred function calls are executed in Last In First Out order after the surrounding function returns.
> 3. Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.

According to first point, when you call `defer TraceError2(err)` , that `err = nil` and that is the value pass to the `TraceError2` function.

`TraceError1(err *error)` works because it is getting a pointer to err, and that pointer value is assigned before defer func `TraceError1` is executed.

Simple example code to explain the behaviour.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)


func main() {
    i := 0
    defer func(i int) {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n",i) //Output: 0
    }(i)

    defer func(i *int) {
        defer fmt.Printf("%d\n",*i) //Output: 1
    }(&i)
    i++
}
```

Comment: sorry @zerkms, I didn't get that

Comment: `err *error` <-- this is called a "pointer to an `error`", not a "reference". There are no references in Go.